# How to get 'id' from an open bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, coffeescript

I have a modal with `id="<%= p.id %>"` (the id of the post that is in the modal). I want to do something with the content of the modal when it is open (and I need to do this in the.js file). But how can I get id from the opened modal into javascript?

I have tried with the javascript code under, but it does not work. Any suggestions?

**_singlePost.html.erb**

```
<a class="fg" href="#<%= p.id %>" data-toggle="modal">
    <div id="withJosefin">
        <%= p.title %>
    </div>
</a>

<div id="<%= p.id %>" class="modal hide" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <p><h3 id="myModalLabel"><%= p.title %></h3></p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <%= raw(p.link) %>
    </div>
</div>
```

**pages.js.coffee**

```
$ ->
  if ('div.modal.hide.in').is(":visible")
    currentId = $('.modal.fade.in').attr('id')
    //Do something with currentId here
```

Comment: I cannot see any jquery code here

Comment: @roasted - it's coffeecrap sprinkled with jQuery !

Comment: Isn't it enough: currentId = $('.modal.fade.in').attr('id')  without 'if' testing for visible. As i understand it, bootstrap add class 'in' for opened modal, no?

Comment: @roasted: I think `currentId = $('.modal.fade.in').attr('id')` will work, but I need to trigger it when an modal is open. So I think I need an `if` statement...(but the one I have written over does not work.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this in the [documentation](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals):

You can create a callback when the modal is shown like this:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown', function () {
  // do something…
})
```

In your case you would have this:

```
//Somewhere in the beginning of your coffeescript/javascript before the modal is opened by the user.

//CoffeeScript
$("div.modal.hide").on "shown", ->
    id = $(this).attr('id')
    //Do whatever you want with the id

//javascript
$('div.modal.hide').on('shown', function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    //Do whatever you want with the id
});
```

Hope that helps

Comment: note that you should use `on.('shown.bs.modal')`  instead of `on.('shown')` for bootstrap 3

Comment: Like above - same for bootstrap 4